# "Fill your boots" Expression

Tags: expressions

I see in a movie this expression, but i'm not understand in the context scene.

In the scene the character gives to another a book. The first one says something that leaves the person who got the book angry. After that the character says "Fill your boots"

Comment: Are you sure they didn't say "fill your boots"? You should find an explanation of that expression online...

Comment: thanks @SamBC. I actually listened wrongly in the movie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As per Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fill-your-boots), it is an instruction or offer to someone that they should take as much as they want of something. It might be something they have to pay for, or something being offered free. It might be food, physical goods of some other sort, or some non-tangible item. It might even be more abstract, such as services or help available from some source.